# Aggregate a value by 2 variables

Tags: r, variables, aggregate, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
AgeBracket    No of People     No of Jobs
18-25               2               5
18-25               2               2
26-34               4               6
35-44               4               0
26-34               2               3 
35-44               1               7
45-54               3               2
```

From this I want to aggregate the data so it looks like the following:

```
AgeBracket     1Person    2People    3People    4People
18-25             0          3.5        0          0
26-34             0           3         0          6
35-44             7           0         0          0
45-54             0           0         2          0
```

So along the Y axis is the Age Bracket and along X (top row) is the number of people while in the cells it show's the average number of jobs for that age bracket and number of people.

I assume it's something to do with aggregation but can't find anything similar to this on any site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming df is your data.frame then you can use aggregate with mean function using **BaseR**, but I think `data.table` way is the faster as suggested by Imo:

```
agg <- aggregate(No.of.Jobs ~ AgeBracket + No.of.People,data=df,mean)
fin <- reshape2::dcast(agg,AgeBracket ~ No.of.People)
fin[is.na(fin)] <- 0
names(fin) <- c("AgeBracket",paste0("People",1:4))
```

As suggested by @Imo, a one-liner could be this:

```
reshape2::dcast(df, AgeBracket ~ No.of.People, value.var="No.of.Jobs", fun.aggregate=mean, fill=0)
```

we need to just rename the columns after that.

**OUtput:**

```
 AgeBracket People1 People2 People3 People4
1      18-25       0     3.5       0       0
2      26-34       0     3.0       0       6
3      35-44       7     0.0       0       0
4      45-54       0     0.0       2       0
```

Comment: Just to note that the syntax of `dcast` is identical `data.table` (v 1.10.4) and `reshape2` (v 1.4.1) packages in this instance, so your first three lines could be collapsed into my first line, like `reshape2::dcast(df, AgeBracket ~ People, value.var="Jobs", fun.aggregate=mean, fill=0)`. Plus one from me.

Comment: @Imo Thanks always great to hear from experts,  I think data.table solution is much better, I know what you are trying to convey I was just trying to make the solution simple.

Comment: Sure thing. Aside from speed, a second advantage of `data.table`'s `dcast` is that it can cast multiple variables at once, which can be pretty handy in wider data sets.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a data.table method using `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)

setnames(dcast(df, AgeBracket ~ People, value.var="Jobs", fun.aggregate=mean, fill=0),
         c("AgeBracket", paste0(sort(unique(df$People)), "Person")))[]
```

Here, `dcast` reshapes wide, putting persons as separate variables. fun.aggregate is used to calculate the mean number of jobs across ageBracket-person cells. fill is set to 0.

`setnames` is used to rename the variables as the default is the integer values. and `[]` at the end is used to print out the result.

```
   AgeBracket 1Person 2Person 3Person 4Person
1:      18-25       0     3.5       0       0
2:      26-34       0     3.0       0       6
3:      35-44       7     0.0       0       0
4:      45-54       0     0.0       2       0
```

This can be stretched out into two lines, which is probably more readable.

```
# reshape wide and calculate means
df.wide <- dcast(df, AgeBracket ~ People, value.var="Jobs", fun.aggregate=mean, fill=0)
# rename variables
setnames(df.wide, c("AgeBracket", paste0(names(df.wide)[-1], "Person")))
```

Comment: Which package/library do I need for dcast?

Comment: Sorry. added that, this version of `dcast` is from `data.table`.

Comment: The `dcast` function from `reshape2` should probably also work without (m)any change(s), but `setnames` is a `data.table` function for renaming the variables.